# how to copy a bone pose of one keyframe to many?

Tags: pose-mode

The target bone is the same.
The armature is the same.

It is a single keyframe used as pose source.
There are more than 30 keyframes that will be the target.

All targets will be set to that single pose, like a reset would do.

And I want that pose to be saved on every keyframe, to avoid interpolation in between in case i set something new.

Can it be done?

Comment: Keyframes can be duplicated, but for 30 you might want scripting. On the other hand, it sounds as if you are “telling Trumpkin nobody’s been killed” as it were. Why not just wait till there is a change, and then duplicate the key frame once and put it right before that?

Comment: Deleting at dopesheet and setting just the first, and again on a keyframe before and after the one i want to change. I guess will be the alternative for now. I should learn scriping, I guess may be easier to code than find a ready specific one somewhere, thx!